# Connect pg routing to HTML webpage for routing application

Tags: javascript, pgrouting, html5

I am trying to create a web based routing application for my final year project. I am currently trying to connect my web page with pg_routing. I have all my features loaded in GeoServer and PostgreSQL. I can connect my features to my web page using WMS from GeoServer (example below), but pg_routing does not function in the same way.

Is there a way to do it and if so, how?

```
var Buildings = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8010/geoserver/wms' , {
    layers: 'IST_Mosaic:Buildings',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true});
```

Comment: You probably want to look at the pgRouting Workshop from chapter 10 and later: https://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.6/en/chapters/geoserver.html
It explains exactly that, but you have to adapt it to your case and data of course.